# remove number from array

Tags: java, arrays, numbers, duplicates

I need to write a program which for a given array of ints prints all its elements, but each value only once, without repetitions. That is my tutor said. I agree that there are several example here, but I have special conditions like:

> Do not create any auxiliary arrays, collections or Strings!
>
> Do not use any classes from packages other than the standard java.lang.

I have been studying Java not so long so here is what I've done:

```
public class Third {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] p = {5, 2, 2, 5, -1, 5, 12, 2, 5, 44, 12, 9};
        remove(p);
    }

    static public void remove(int[] a) {

        int min = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < a.length; j++) {
                if (a[i] == a[j]) {
                    a[i] = min;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
            if (a[j] != min) {
                System.out.println( a[j] );
            }
        }

    }

}
```

I realize that this is not efficient, because it is not able to print int's min value. So is there any other way to do it correctly ?

Comment: So basically you want to remove duplicates in place? The problem you have with the min value is that you're lacking a specification - what will you do about the empty spaces? They'll need to have some value which must be a duplicate if there is more than one...

Comment: Never put more information into comments; update your question instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you said that you want to print the elements of the array only once, but you cannot use any structures or other arrays to achieve that, I believe your best strategy is to simply scan the array and look for elements with the same value from the index forward, and only print if you haven't found any.

For example: for the array `{5, 2, 2, 5, -1, 5, 12, 2, 5, 44, 12, 9}`, when you look at the first `5`, you'll see three more fives to your right so you won't print anything, but when you look at that fourth `5`, there'll be non and so you'll print it. When you see `-1`, for example, you won't see any other `-1` to your right, and you'll print it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] p = {5, 2, 2, 5, -1, 5, 12, 2, 5, 44, 12, 9};
    remove(p);
}

static public void remove(int[] a) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        boolean found = false;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < a.length; j++) {
            if (a[i] == a[j]) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found)
            System.out.println(a[i]);
    }

}
```

And the output for your array will be:

```
-1
2
5
44
12
9
```

Every element is only printed once

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question here i am providing solution. In this first i am sorting  `array` in ascending order  then i am printing current index `a[i]` if it is not equal to next index `a[i+1]` .

program:

```
int a[] = { 5, 2, 2, 5, -1, 5, 12, 2, 5, 44, 12, 9};
        int temp = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {

            for (int j = i; j < a.length; j++)
                if (a[i] > a[j]) {
                    temp = a[i];
                    a[i] = a[j];
                    a[j] = temp;

                }

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
            if (a[i] != a[i + 1]) {
                System.out.println(a[i]);
            } 
            if (i == a.length - 2)
                System.out.println(a[i + 1]);

        }
```

output:

```
-1
2
5
9
12
44
```

Hope it will help you.